# How can I check the hardware of a Mac Pro 1,1 running 10.6.8?

Tags: mac-pro

Mac Pro 1,1 running OS 10.6.8, I am having finder freezes that forces me to force quit using the power button. I do not have the disks that shipped with this computer which would have included Apple Hardware Test. I have downloaded what is said to be the AHT for this computer but I can't get it to run from a disk that I burned.

Answer (score 1):

Download the AHT for your [computer model](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/018-2769-A.dmg) and use the contents to restore the /System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics folder, then reboot while holding <kbd>D</kbd> to start the diagnostic tools.

There's no need to burn something to disc.